# Pass attribute into struts2 action via struts.xml

Tags: struts2

How can I pass an attribute into my struts2 java action that tells me whether the action was called from one URL path / action mapping vs another?

I figured I could put something in the struts.xml for two action mappings but use the same java action and just pass in a flag into the action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the `<param/>` tag. I do this frequently for actions that handle both adding and editing an entity, as the fields, validations, and whatnot are virtually identical. Here's an example of that.

### struts.xml

```
<action name="users/add" class="AddEditUserAction">
  <param name="edit">false</param>
  <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/addEditUser.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="users/{username}/edit" class="AddEditUserAction">
  <param name="edit">true</param>
  <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/addEditUser.jsp</result>
</action>
```

### The Action

```
public class AddEditUserAction {
  private boolean isEdit;

  // this is called by the struts.xml to set the value
  public void setEdit(final boolean edit) {
    isEdit = edit;
  }
}
```

In order for this to work, you need the static parameters interceptor in your stack (it's included by default).

Comment: The "method" approach is shorter, and IMO, more immediately communicative.

Comment: I don't see how it would be shorter. Perhaps you can expand your answer to include an example?

Comment: Because `method="edit"` is shorter than `<param name="edit">true</param>`. For me the communication aspect is more important than the absolute chars, though.

Comment: The character difference is negligible. Since in this particular example, I am using the same action method to display the add/edit form (input), the same validate method, and the same method to process the form (execute), I'll stick with my approach. For other scenarios, yours may be a better fit. Thanks!

Comment: If everything is the same, I don't see the point of differentiating at all. All I'm saying is that there's less cognitive overhead when reading the config file using the method... method.

Comment: It's just to provide the different URLs (add vs edit) and the contextual changes that come along with that "Add User" vs. "Update User". From a code perspective, there is very minimal difference.

Answer (score 0):

I question the design.

I'd handle it by specifying a method in the action configuration for one or both mappings.

The method(s) would set a flag in the action and call the "guts" of the action, which would query the flag value, and proceed accordingly.